# How to fit full cell with an image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I want cell's background to be completely filled with an image, but I am unable to do it. 
I have tried all of image scalings, but none of them helped. 
Code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
    myCell.backgroundColor = .red
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myCell.frame.width , height: myCell.frame.height))
    let image = UIImage(named: "background")
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    myCell.backgroundView = UIView()
    myCell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)
    
    return myCell
}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Maybe the problem is in my imageView's frame? I think its not because I tested with changing imageView's background colour and all the cell's red colour was overlayed with blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use constraints here so add this [extension](https://gist.github.com/NikhilManapure/1eeb64205a0df0dcbb45705c0caf2070) to a file in your project.

And then instead of

```
myCell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)
```

Do this

```
myCell.backgroundView!.embedView(imageView)
```

You might want to read more about Autolayout n Constraints, so [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html) are docs

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're adding the image to the cell's `contentView`.

Add the following to `cellForItemAt`: `cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

Here's my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. I'm anchoring the `UIImageView` to the cell's `contentView`:

```
struct CustomData {
    var title: String
    var url: String
    var backgroundImage: UIImage
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var data: CustomData? {
        didSet {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            imageView.image = data.backgroundImage
            
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return iv
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: id didnt help me

Comment: @stackich I've updated my answer. Please take another look.